# I live in a spaceship

Tags: riddle, knowledge, rhyme, language, limerick

> I live in a spaceship that travels so 快地,
>   along with a doctor who I find 真帅的,
>   my features are 美丽,
>   my name rhymes with 内力,
>   it's my job to fix if the engine goes 坏了.

Who am I?

Comment: As someone who speaks Chinese, I really love the rhyming limerick. So rare to see :) :)

Comment: wow nice one... as a person who speaks Chinese, i have to say... this is awesome

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Surely you must be

> [Kaylee](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0303461/characters/nm0821612?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t6) from [Firefly](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0303461/?ref_=tt_ch).

First of all, all the clues are partly in Chinese.

> In the series, all the [cursing was done in Chinese](http://www.browncoats.com/index.php?ContentID=42e83b412a309) to avoid an R rating.

I live in a spaceship that travels so 快地,

> The spaceship Firefly travels very 快地.

along with a doctor who I find 真帅的,

> [This guy](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0303461/characters/nm0536883?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t7) is, indeed, quite 真帅的.

my features are 美丽,

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqRV1l4JOGs

my name rhymes with 内力,

> "Kaylee" does indeed rhyme with "Nèilì"

it's my job to fix if the engine goes 坏了.

> She is the mechanic of the spaceship, and the engine does actually go 坏了 occasionally.

If you don't read (or speak) Chinese all too well, don't worry, [neither do I](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fpuzzling.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F73692%2Fi-live-in-a-spaceship), and [neither did the cast](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51528/how-accurate-is-the-chinese-spoken-in-firefly).

Comment: 叮叮叮, we have a winner!

Answer (score 4):

According to google translate:

> I live in a spaceship that travels so *quickly*,
>  along with a doctor who I find *really handsome*,
>  my features are *beautiful*,
>  my name rhymes with *Internal force*,
>  it's my job to fix if the engine goes *broken*.

Assuming the translation is a bit off so it ruins the rhyme, I'm going to guess you're:

> Montgomery Scott/Scotty from Star Trek

Because:

> He lives on the Enterprise.
>  So does Leonard McCoy/Bones, a handsome doctor.
>  If memory serves, he has a big ego.
>  Not sure about this part, but I'm guessing google translate ruined it.
>  Scotty is the chief engineer and always fixing the engine.

Comment: The translation looks good. This is pretty close, but like you said the fourth line doesn't really fit.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the intended solution, but-

> Space travels with doctor kinda sounds like Doctor Who, SO that would make the answer his companion - Sarah jane